# Way of grouping multiple repos of the same project on Github?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have the following problem, i'm developing a microservice-based app and i have multiple repos in Github. Is any way of grouping all that repos under a project name in order to have kind of having it more organized instead of having all the repositories lost between all the other repos of mine?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you take a look at [git submodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/) in GitHub, does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple repositories in one project, for example a project has many related projects but it is still separate, each of them would have it's own repository. This would be organised.

You can move the repositories using the `mv` command, you will need to check settings, and the local and remote paths afterwards.